# How can I truncate the contents of a textarea using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a text field, I am using `onkeypress` to check the length of the entered string. If it exceeds n number of characters it will return false and it will not accept any other character, but Here I am unable to remove the characters I don't want in the text field. How can I remove the text here.

Comment: simply use maxlength feature of textfield

Comment: @komal - unless we're talking about textarea tag

Comment: same with textarea..http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_maxlength

Comment: @komal: Here I can not use maxlength as I want to restrict the user based on string byte length not the number of charters.  So I going to js function to calculate the byte of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, if you are using `textarea`

```
<textarea onkeypress="return limitlength(this, 20)" style="width: 300px; height: 90px"></textarea>

 function limitlength(obj, length){
    var maxlength=length
    if (obj.value.length>maxlength)
     obj.value=obj.value.substring(0, maxlength)
 }
```

Comment: Agarwal: thanks for the tip, Now i am re-assigning the text when it exceeds my limit :)

Answer (score 1):

Use simple HTML5, no need javascript:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5"/>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: it will check the number of characters in string but i need total bytes of the string

Comment: You haven't mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @speti43: it is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the entered text in Onkeyup event. If it is greter than  n then use substring to truncate first n characters and then set  the new string as the value

```
   $("#mytxt").onkeyup(function(){

 var Currentlength =$(this).val().length;
 var CurrentVal = $(this).val();
 if(Currentlength > n)
 {
  $(this).val(CurrentVal.substring(0,n));
  return false;
 } 
});
```

Comment: OP is not asking JQUERY?

Comment: yes Amit , My mistake i should have rewritten it in pure javascript.